# Resizing font size in javascript based off input from user

Tags: javascript, text, fonts, size, calculator

I was wondering how you can resize text size in javascript based off of user input. Say for example, if the input exceeds 1000000000, then set text size to 14. The userinput in this case would be the Price and the size I would like to modify is the the TotalAmount and TipAmount.

Comment: element.style["font-size"] inside of a switch statement

Comment: I am not familiar with a switch statement but thank you for taking your time to respond

Comment: Please provide code of what you already tried and give a little more context.

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```js
function changeTextSize() {
  var input = document.getElementById('input').value;
  
  document.getElementById('text').style.fontSize = input + "px";
}
```

```html
<p id="text">I am some text.</p>
<input type="text" onkeyup="changeTextSize()" id="input">
```

---

Or like this?

```js
function changeTextSize() {
  var input = document.getElementById('input').value;

  if (input > 1000) {
    document.getElementById('text').style.fontSize = 30 + "px"; // Changed 14 to 30, because 14 would be smaller than the default text size
  }
}
```

```html
<p id="text">I am some Text</p>
<input type="text" onkeyup="changeTextSize()" id="input">
```

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you are looking for?

```js
var priceInput = document.getElementById('price-input');
priceInput.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  var price = parseInt(e.target.value);
  priceInput.style.fontSize = price > 10 ? "14px" : "10px";
});
```

```html
<input id="price-input" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You may apply styles with JS.

Given that input and outputs are strings:

```
if(price > 10000){outputElement.style.fontSize = "0.8em"}
```

Comment: `14` is not a valid font-size value, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size

Comment: Updating now :-) Thanks!